# How do I convert dictionary list values to integers?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer, python-3.5

I'm working in Python 3.5. I've uploaded a CSV file and made it into a dictionary. However, the list of multiple values for each key is a string and not an integer. How can I convert the values for each key into an integer?

Furthermore, is there a way for future CSV importation to automatically make dictionary value lists into integers?

So far this is what I have:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
dictname = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    if key in dictname:
        pass
    dictname[key] = row[1:]

print dictname
```

Comment: Where is the example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a function to first check if the value is a string/unicode. If so, it then tries to convert it to a float, e.g. "1,234.45" -> 1234.45.  If this fails or the value is not a string/float, the function returns it unchanged.

This function is then used in a list comprehension to population the dictionary.

Note that the `if key in dictname: pass` block doesn't do anything.  If there are duplicate keys in your data, you have three options:

1) Overwrite the existing key's data with the new row that has the identical key value (this is what is currently happening).

2) Only use the first occurrence of the key row. In this case, change `pass` to `continue`.

3) Try to aggregate the data.  This is more complicated and beyond the scope of your original question, so I will leave it to you to figure out or post a new question covering this scope.

```
def convert_to_numeric(value):
    if isinstance(i, (str, unicode)):
        try:
            result = float(value)
        except:
            pass  # Returns result on next line.
    return result

for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    if key in dictname:
        pass  # This doesn't do anything. Use `continue` to avoid overwriting.
    dictname[key] = [convert_to_numeric(i) for i in row[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if row is the list containing the integers under string format :

```
dictname[key] = [int(elt) for elt in row[1:] if elt.isdigit()]
```

should do the trick

Comment: can I perform that for all keys?

Comment: You should be able to, as I'm taking all digits from the list `row[1:]` and creating a list of int from it. So, as long as the elements have a digit format, it should work.

Comment: what I meant, was could I immediately select all keys instead of having to go over one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and specify converter functions. In fact you may not even need to do that as it is intelligently parsing CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

If you need converter functions:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv',converters={'yourintegercolumn':int})
```

Comment: While it's an option - it could be a sledgehammer to a nut approach depending what the OP is trying to do...

Comment: @JonClements: good point. I will delete this answer if you think I should.

Comment: Up to you - it's a valid answer after all... unless it just so happens the OP is going to be doing post processing work on it that requires pandas, I'm not sure it's entirely useful though...

Comment: Thanks, @JonClements. I will leave it for now.